# R - classification the number - assign labels

Tags: r, classification

How to convert the numeric data to string, not the datatype change, but the classification in R? Say, I got 100 numbers 0:1, and if it's > 0.5, then I need to assign a name of "Good", otherwise it's "Bad".

Comment: Like this?  nums <- seq(0,1, by = .01); nums.good <- ifelse(nums > .5, "Good", "Bad")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wish to do it using factors?

```
a=runif(100, 0, 1) > 0.5
b=factor(a, c(FALSE,TRUE), labels=c("Bad","Good"))
c=as.character(b)
```

Alternatively, if you just want to change the names in the vector, a, then:

```
a=runif(100, 0, 1) > 0.5
c=ifelse(a,"Good","Bad")
names(a)=c
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 nums <- seq(0,1, by = .01)
 res <- c('Bad', 'Good')[(nums > 0.5)+1]
```